# How do I access a dictionary value, with a variable for the key, if it is wrapped in eval?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I am using a variable to name a specific dictionary and using the eval() function to do this. The user input is from tkinter.

```
x6x6 = {"2":r"arrays\2x1_6x6_2up.txt", "4":r"arrays\2x2_6x6_4up.txt", "8":"arrays\2x4_6x6_8up.txt"}

mydict = "x%sx%s" % (numX.get(), numY.get())

numPnls = pnls.get()
```

If I use the variable numPnls plainly I get TypeError: string indices must be integers:

```
print(eval(mydict[numPnls]))
```

If I try to eval it also I get IndexError: string index out of range:

```
print(eval(mydict[eval(numPnls)]))
```

This produces the expected results:

```
print(x6x6[numPnls])
```

and this prints everything:

```
print(eval(mydict))
```

Comment: What is `numPnls`? Where is it defined in your code?

Comment: It is a string, also from a tkinter field

Comment: Rather than storing your dicts in separate variables, it sounds like they should be stored in an outer dict or some other data structure.

Comment: That worked, I didnt know you could do that. I still dont understand why the original scenario is behaving like that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had the syntax wrong:

```
print(eval(mydict)[numPnls])
```

using user2357112's method of a 2d dictionary though, much easier:

```
print(outerdict[mydict][numPnls])
```